# Errors building Tensorflow from source with Bazel

Tags: python, tensorflow, bazel

I am trying to convert my SSD MobileNet graph file to tflite format but i am getting a lot of errors building Tensorflow from source (im following [this](https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Lite-Object-Detection-on-Android-and-Raspberry-Pi) tutorial).

Tensorflow version is 1.13

Bazel version is 0.21.0- (@non-git)

OS is Win10

This is my configuration

```
(src) C:\tensorflow-build\tensorflow>python ./configure.py
WARNING: The following rc files are no longer being read, please transfer their contents or import their path into one of the standard rc files:
nul
WARNING: --batch mode is deprecated. Please instead explicitly shut down your Bazel server using the command "bazel shutdown".
INFO: Invocation ID: e7444880-8c68-4c42-9062-ca33135fde40
You have bazel 0.21.0- (@non-git) installed.
Please specify the location of python. [Default is C:\Users\rilmts\anaconda3\envs\src\python.exe]:


Found possible Python library paths:
 C:\Users\rilmts\anaconda3\envs\src\lib\site-packages
Please input the desired Python library path to use.  Default is [C:\Users\rilmts\anaconda3\envs\src\lib\site-packages]

Do you wish to build TensorFlow with XLA JIT support? [y/N]:
No XLA JIT support will be enabled for TensorFlow.

Do you wish to build TensorFlow with ROCm support? [y/N]:
No ROCm support will be enabled for TensorFlow.

Do you wish to build TensorFlow with CUDA support? [y/N]:
No CUDA support will be enabled for TensorFlow.

Please specify optimization flags to use during compilation when bazel option "--config=opt" is specified [Default is /arch:AVX]:

Would you like to override eigen strong inline for some C++ compilation to reduce the compilation time? [Y/n]: y
Eigen strong inline overridden.
```

The command i used

```
bazel build --config=opt //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
```

Here are the errors

```
(src) C:\tensorflow-build\tensorflow>bazel build --config=opt //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
WARNING: The following rc files are no longer being read, please transfer their contents or import their path into one of the standard rc files:
c:\tensorflow-build\tensorflow/.bazelrc
Starting local Bazel server and connecting to it...
WARNING: Option 'experimental_shortened_obj_file_path' is deprecated
INFO: Invocation ID: 5c1a8d72-71bb-4621-8a24-2052ffcdc30d
ERROR: C:/tensorflow-build/tensorflow/tensorflow/python/tools/api/generator/BUILD:38:1: In rule 'create_python_api_test', size 'medium' is not a valid size.
ERROR: C:/tensorflow-build/tensorflow/tensorflow/python/tools/api/generator/BUILD:38:1: In rule 'create_python_api_test', timeout 'illegal' is not a valid timeout.
ERROR: C:/tensorflow-build/tensorflow/tensorflow/python/tools/api/generator/BUILD:52:1: In rule 'tensorflow_doc_srcs_test', size 'medium' is not a valid size.
ERROR: C:/tensorflow-build/tensorflow/tensorflow/python/tools/api/generator/BUILD:52:1: In rule 'tensorflow_doc_srcs_test', timeout 'illegal' is not a valid timeout.
ERROR: C:/tensorflow-build/tensorflow/tensorflow/python/tools/api/generator/BUILD:68:1: In rule 'output_init_files_test', size 'medium' is not a valid size.
```

I got more than hundred of these "In rule" errors so not going to paste all of them.

And it ends like this

```
ERROR: C:/tensorflow-build/tensorflow/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/BUILD:138:1: Target '//tensorflow/contrib/slim/python/slim/data:data_pip' contains an error and its package is in error and referenced by '//tensorflow/tools/pip_package:simple_console_for_windows'
ERROR: C:/tensorflow-build/tensorflow/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/BUILD:138:1: Target '//tensorflow/contrib/slim/python/slim/nets:nets_pip' contains an error and its package is in error and referenced by '//tensorflow/tools/pip_package:simple_console_for_windows'
ERROR: C:/tensorflow-build/tensorflow/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/BUILD:138:1: Target '//tensorflow/contrib/specs:specs' contains an error and its package is in error and referenced by '//tensorflow/tools/pip_package:simple_console_for_windows'
ERROR: C:/tensorflow-build/tensorflow/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/BUILD:138:1: Target '//tensorflow/contrib/summary:summary_test_util' contains an error and its package is in error and referenced by '//tensorflow/tools/pip_package:simple_console_for_windows'
ERROR: C:/tensorflow-build/tensorflow/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/BUILD:138:1: Target '//tensorflow/contrib/tensor_forest/hybrid:hybrid_pip' contains an error and its package is in error and referenced by '//tensorflow/tools/pip_package:simple_console_for_windows'
ERROR: C:/tensorflow-build/tensorflow/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/BUILD:138:1: Target '//tensorflow/contrib/tpu:tpu' contains an error and its package is in error and referenced by '//tensorflow/tools/pip_package:simple_console_for_windows'
ERROR: C:/tensorflow-build/tensorflow/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/BUILD:138:1: Target '//tensorflow/python:pywrap_tensorflow_import_lib_file' contains an error and its package is in error and referenced by '//tensorflow/tools/pip_package:simple_console_for_windows'
ERROR: Analysis of target '//tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package' failed; build aborted: Cannot compute config conditions
INFO: Elapsed time: 5,320s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (63 packages loaded, 47 targets configured)
    currently loading: tensorflow/core/kernels
    Fetching @six_archive; Restarting.

(src) C:\tensorflow-build\tensorflow>
```

I've tried it with Tensorflow 1.14 and Bazel 0.24.1 and got similar errors but the last error changes to

```
ERROR: Analysis of target '//tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package' failed; build aborted: Analysis failed
```

I've been struggling with this for three days now. I tried researching the errors but couldn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running `./configure` as mentioned [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4279#issuecomment-246003587)

Comment: Yes I have tried `python ./configure.py`